# Why doesn't the assignment to Object.matrix_local change in the script, unlike matrix_world?

Tags: python, scripting

As in the following code, **matrix_local** does not change before and after executing `obj.matrix_local = Matrix.Rotation(math.pi/6, 4, 'X')`.

```
# Blender 3.6.0

import bpy
import math
from mathutils import Matrix

print("")
print("matrix_local:")

bpy.ops.object.rotation_clear(clear_delta=True)

obj = bpy.context.active_object
mat_prev = obj.matrix_local.copy()
obj.matrix_local = Matrix.Rotation(math.pi/6, 4, 'X')

print("After - Before =" )
print(obj.matrix_local - mat_prev)
```

```
OUTPUT
matrix_local:
After - Before =
<Matrix 4x4 (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
```

On the other hand, using **matrix_world** or **matrix_basis** instead of matrix_local changed them.

```
OUTPUT
matrix_world:
After - Before =
<Matrix 4x4 (0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, -0.1340, -0.5000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.5000, -0.1340, 0.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)>
```

It's weird that the behavior changes depending on the type of matrix. I asked the reason because it might cause trouble in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll quote blender dev response [on the same issue](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/90036#issuecomment-202601).

> The matrix_local property doesn't really exist in the object.
>
> When you assign the obj.matrix_local the matrix gets decomposed and
> assigned to loc/rot/scale components of the object. (The parent
> inverse matrix is "cancelled" from the matrix before decomposition).
> Can follow `rna_Object_matrix_local_set` -> `BKE_object_apply_mat4` When
> you read the property it is read from object's evaluated matrix
> (Object::obmat). The parent object's inverse matrix is "cancelled"
> from it as well (to get local matrix, as the property name suggests).
> The obmat is evaluated by the dependency graph, so that it will have
> constraints properly taken into account. Can follow that via
> `rna_Object_matrix_local_get` -> `BKE_object_matrix_local_get`

I can illustrate it with code from blender tracker. If you run it in default blender scene you can see from system console that `matrix_local` is appearing to be unchanged. BUT if you update view_layer after you assign new matrix to `matrix_local` (uncomment line in the code below to do that), you'll see that `matrix_local` is now also updated.

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix


print("--------------------------------")
obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
print("Before: ", obj.matrix_local)
m = Matrix.Translation((2.0, 3.0, 4.0))
obj.matrix_local = m

# uncomment the line below for matrix to update
# bpy.context.view_layer.update()
print("After: ", obj.matrix_local)
```

PS Agree that it's a bit weird and probably should be documented in [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.matrix_local).